# Multiple instances of a single Userform / the need for pointers

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a Userform that lets the user pick a worksheet from a list of open worksheets. I need this Userform in various places of my macro, for various purposes; for example, to specify the worksheet containing "sales" data, and to specify the worksheet containing "stock" data. The objects `wsSales` and `wsStock` should point to the appropriate worksheets, so that my macro can later work on these.

How can I give each instance of my Userform a different behavior? One instance should set `wsSales` to the user-selected worksheet, the other instance should set `wsStock` to the user-selected worksheet.

I have thought about putting several "OK" buttons on my Useform, and making only one visible per instance. Each OK button would have different code. But that's not very elegant, because I would have to put as much "OK" buttons as there are possible uses for my Userform and it would become quite a mess in more complex situations. So, ideally, I would use a property of my Userform as a pointer to either `wsSales` or `wsStock`, but I've read that pointers don't exist in VBA. Then, what's the best way to have two instances of a Userform behave differently?

Comment: How does the UserForm get called? ie from specific sheets,or as part of other code?

Comment: One option would be to store the sheet name in the `UserForm.Tag` property.

Comment: This UserForm (let's call it "ufPickSheet") is called from another UserForm (let's call it "ufMain"). ufMain has two "Select sheet" buttons, each calling a different instance of the ufPicksheet UserForm, and setting its properties.

Comment: Are you actually declaring variables as instances of the userform?  If not, you should.  You might want to look at this post: http://yoursumbuddy.com/a-flexible-vba-chooser-form/.

Comment: Thanks Doug! Calling the UserForm from a function which then returns the user's choice seems to solve my problem.

Comment: @Doug, please post your comment as an answer so it can be marked as solved.  Then we all know this question and no more help is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you actually declaring variables as instances of the userform? If not, you should. You might want to look at this post: [yoursumbuddy.com/a-flexible-vba-chooser-form](http://yoursumbuddy.com/a-flexible-vba-chooser-form).

Answer (score 0):

I am using a kind of common approach by means one can practically use any kind of information to create and uniquely identify one of multiple instances of a UserForm - which doesn't even require a variable for an instance. See https://warbe-maker.github.io/vba/common/2021/11/09/UserForm-Instances.html.